# Any metric space can be isometrically embed in some Banach space?

Tags: reference-request, metric-spaces, banach-spaces

I have just read the question of the title in an article from Kirchheim. I didn't know this result, does any one know where I can find a proof of it?

Comment: If you google [metric space embeds in banach](https://www.google.com.ar/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=metric+space+embeds+in+banach&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gfe_rd=cr&ei=9geJV5TCIKbX8geTiaKIAQ) the very **first** result is the Wikipedia article on Kuratowski's embedding. The second result is a question here in MSE, with a link to the Wikipedia article.

Comment: You're right, I haven't had the google reflex. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

One such proof is via the so-called [Kuratowski embedding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kuratowski_embedding).

Comment: Ok, thank you very much!